# application for mobile devices

Tags: android

there are so many platfroms mac/Andriod/windows. can we make one application which will work on all platform  I don't want make seperate binaries for all platforms. will j2me help us in achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Web application based on HTML 5

Answer (score 0):

The opinion of this does not sound very high from what I have herd.

There are options such as PhoneGap (based on HTML5). There are others also on the market.

There are compilers which can build native applications for most platforms by adobe (flash & flex based).